# Recaptcha::RecaptchaError in Articles#show No site key specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get:

> "Recaptcha::RecaptchaError in Articles#show No site key specified."

And I do not understand where is my mistake.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', :require => 'dotenv/rails-now'
gem "recaptcha", require: "recaptcha/rails"
```

.env

```
export RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = '*******************************'
export RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = '*******************************'
```

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "admin", password: "**************", only: :destroy

  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
end
```

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "admin", password: "**********", except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 11):

It looks like your using [this gem](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha), which specifies that you need:

> export RECAPTCHA_**SITE**_KEY  = '6Lc6BAAAAAAAAChqRbQZcn_yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
>
> export RECAPTCHA_**SECRET**_KEY = '6Lc6BAAAAAAAAKN3DRm6VA_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

when I follow your link, you have

> export RECAPTCHA_**PUBLIC**_KEY = \'*******************************\'
>
> export RECAPTCHA_**PRIVATE**_KEY = \'*******************************\'

Comment: No. My file .env:      export RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = '********************************'
export RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = '****************************'

Comment: yeah, in your .env you have RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY and RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY but assuming you're using the gem I linked and not a different one, you need to be using RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY and  RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY, so changing PUBLIC to SITE and PRIVATE with SECRET should fix your problem.

Comment: You should click on accept answer if that solved your issue.